What's a word for the feeling when a friend doesn't share grief or sadness and acts like nothing happened?
Imagine you have two friends. The three of you are driving to a party, in good spirits, until you crash. Your friend, the driver, dies; but you and your other friend survive. The next day you begin to mourn dutifully, however, your pal, the other survivor, keeps on partying and living life to the fullest. All three of you were the greatest of friends so you've only wanted happiness for each other. Except now you feel...?
-'Bitter' I suppose, but bitter doesn't make sense because you truly do want your friend to be happy.
-You would be happier/comforted if they were also miserable, so you could say 'schadenfreude', but that too, seems incorrect because you won't feel joyful, and you don't actually wish them misfortune
So what word encapsulates this desire, where misery loves company, and loathes stoicism?

This is the opposite of schadenfreude: you feel upset because your friend is not feeling bad.

Presumably you feel sad because your friend is dead. You feel happiness when your surviving friend's emotions fall in line with the yours, or with what is considered normal.

Sounds like you're feeling conflicted.

This is not that related to schadenfreude. The opposite of schadenfreude is usually described as 'pleasure from the good fortune of others,' which doesn't apply here. You might consider 'reverse schadenfreude' (displeasure from the good fortune of others), but even that doesn't quite fit your context.

Now you feel betrayed by his lack of empathy.

There is also What's the phrase/idiom for being very disappointed in someone?.

You are perhaps disappointed....
You are perhaps feeling alienated.
You are wanting for solidarity....
You might be wanting for synergism

The opposite of Schadenfreude is:
Finding pleasure in another person’s good fortune is what social scientists call “freudenfreude,” a term (inspired by the German word for “joy”) that describes the bliss we feel when someone else succeeds, even if it doesn’t directly involve us. Freudenfreude is like social glue, said Catherine Chambliss, a professor of psychology at Ursinus College. It makes relationships “more intimate and enjoyable.”
Source:
https://www.nytimes.com/2022/11/25/well/mind/schadenfreude-freudenfreude.html#:~:text=The%20Opposite%20of%20Schadenfreude%20Is,success%20comes%20with%20many%20benefits.
